# css overflow 'auto' on edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I need to hide the overflow scroll bar on Edge.

I have the current properties on the required scroll area and it's working in macos chrome/safari.

`height: "240px", maxHeight: "240px", overflowY: "auto"`

I also added the following

```
  html {
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
```

**Desire Behavior**
The scroll bar should hide, unless user is scrolling.

How can I auto hide the bars?

[image]

Comment: Is this for the Trident/IE rebrand or the Blink/Chrome rebrand? Because they are two completely different engines.

Comment: This will be a big question for me as well, since I am a mac User and I want to try to make the appearance work on microsoft windows. I'm testing it on chrome and Edge of windows 10, not sure which brand is it

Comment: Please do not put answers in the question. If you got an answer that is not already in the post then add it as an answer. Not as an addition to the question

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Go to the site in my profile and look at the sidebar about half way down and it will tell you either MSIE or Chrome. I don't test browsers, I test *engines*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these attributes to the container:

```
onmouseover="this.style.overflowY='scroll'" onmouseout="this.style.overflow='hidden'"
```

And set set `overflow: hidden;`.

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/GRjXmQW

Comment: thank u, i use the :hover method. instead but your answer pointed me to the right place. Refer my question for the :hover method

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

From the accepted answer, I modified and use :hover to get the desire behavior.

```
    .mydiv {
        overflow-y: 'hidden'
     }
     .mydiv:hover {
         overflow-y: 'auto'
     }
```